# How to disable automatic retry for DevForce requests

Tags: c#, timeout, devforce

We have noticed that when a DevForce request times out, it is automatically retried.  This behavior has also been mentioned on the forums [here](http://www.ideablade.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=4661&title=server-side-methods-called-twice).  In that forum post, the suggested solution is to increase the timeout to try to avoid the problem altogether.  For us, that is not really a possible solution.  There are some operations that we know will timeout and increasing the timeout is not an acceptable solution.

Worse, if the call is a Stored Procedure query or an InvokeServerMethod call, it's very possible that the call is not [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) so retrying it again is not safe and could very likely end up doing more harm than good.  We've started running into cases like that in our app and it is causing major pains.  A simple example would be: we call a stored procedure that creates a Copy of an item.  If the copy takes too long, it will keep getting retried but that just means we have 3 copy operations all going in parallel.  The end result is that the end user gets an error (because the 3rd rety still times out) but there (eventually) will be three copies of the item (the stored procedure will eventually finish - the retry logic doesn't seem to cancel the previous requests - and I'm not even sure such cancelling is possible).  And that is one of the more benign examples - in other cases, the retried operations can cause even worse problems.

I see from the [6.1.6 release notes](http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/616-release-notes), that DevForce no longer performs automatic retry for Saves.  I'd really like to see that behavior extended to StoredProcedureQueries and InvokeServerMethods.  For normal EntityQuery operations (and probably even Connect/Disconnect calls), I'm fine with the rety.  If this isn't something that can be changed in the core of DevForce, is there a way to make it configurable or provide some custom way for us to inject code that controls this?

Comment: Are we talking about DevForce 2010 or 2012?  In DF2010, InvokeServerMethod, like SaveChanges, should not be doing a retry.  In DF2012, there's an outstanding feature request to make auto retry configurable in some way, and we should probably bump up the priority and implement this.  A feature request for DF2010 is also still an option, but lower priority.

Comment: I should add too that in DF2012 if you're doing async calls you can use a CancellationToken to work around the retry issue.

Comment: I'm on DevForce 2012.  As for CancellationToken, how would that help?  I'm not the one doing the retry so I'm not sure what I would cancel.  And that kind of cancelling isn't going to stop a stored procedure or other server-side operation, right?  It's more just that the client abandons the request?

Comment: If you provide a CancellationToken to an async EntityManager call and set it to cancel after a certain period, the client will abandon the request.  This isn't all that different from a WCF channel timeout, which also leaves the server request running.  Which is why it's probably a good idea to increase your WCF timeout values if that's the type of timeout you're seeing.

Comment: Increasing the timeout seems like it will just lead to an arms race.  I increase the timeout to 10 minutes. But then I have the same problems with an 11 minute request.  I increase the timeout to 20 minutes, then I have the same problem with a 21 minute request, etc.  In some cases, a higher timeout could be helpful but it's not really what we are looking for.  And it would be nice to avoid having to update every asynchronous call to include a CancellationToken. That would be a lot of changes for us. Being able to configure the retry logic seems much more promising to me... :-)

Comment: I agree, a configurable retry is a better solution, I was just offering a possible workaround.  This feature should go in the next release, but I don't have a date for that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto retry behavior for communication failures is configurable in the 7.2.4 release now available.  See the [release notes](http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/Documentation/release-notes#H7.2.4) for usage information.

Comment: The configurability in 7.2.4 is exactly what we need.  We've disabled auto-retry for everything except simple queries (specifically, disabled it for Stored Procedure calls and InvokeServerMethod calls).